# BigInteger throwing NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, noclassdeffounderror, biginteger

Im trying to solve a code golf problem, but I ran into an unexpected issue. It seems like Java's BigInteger class is throwing a NoClassDefFoundError. Here is my code -

```
import java.math.BigInteger;

public class UnGolfed {
    int sum=0;
    BigInteger num = new BigInteger("0");
    int left;
    UnGolfed(int i){
        left=i;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        (new UnGolfed(Integer.parseInt("1"))).doIt();
    }

    void doIt() {
        for(int i=left;i>0;i--){
            sum+=getNextHappy(num=num.nextProbablePrime());
        }
        System.out.print(sum);  
    }

    int getNextHappy(BigInteger b) {
        try{
            String s = b.toString();
            int tSum=0;
            for(char c : s.toCharArray()){
                tSum+=(c-48)*(c-48);
            }
            if(tSum==1) return num.intValue();
            return getNextHappy(new BigInteger(tSum+""));
        }
        catch(StackOverflowError e){
            return getNextHappy(num=num.nextProbablePrime());
        }       
    }
}
```

If you are curious its for a code golf challenge to find the sum of the first N happy prime numbers. When I run it though I get the following  -

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class java.security.SecureRandom
    at java.math.BigInteger.getSecureRandom(BigInteger.java:875)
    at java.math.BigInteger.passesMillerRabin(BigInteger.java:898)
    at java.math.BigInteger.primeToCertainty(BigInteger.java:739)
    at java.math.BigInteger.nextProbablePrime(BigInteger.java:690)
    at UnGolfed.getNextHappy(UnGolfed.java:33)
    at UnGolfed.getNextHappy(UnGolfed.java:30)
    at UnGolfed.getNextHappy(UnGolfed.java:30)
    .....
    .....
    .....
```

NOTE: I know this code has many issues (likely runs into an infinite loop and causes a stack overflow error, among other things). Please ignore those, I can figure them out later. I just want to know why this NoClassDefFoundError is coming up

Comment: How are you running this code? Seems to be compilable and runnable despite the issues it has.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Its in an Eclipse project.

Comment: First of all... why are you using recursion in the catch block of a StackOverflowException... seems like filling firehoses with alcohol

Comment: Why use BigInteger??? Unless it's for your homework, I don't understand this overhead. Use int. It causes you to do so much unnecessary manipulations.

Comment: Probably because you have overflowed your stack, and as a response you're trying to call BigInteger.nextProbablyPrime with very few space left on the stack, so during the initialization of class SecureRandom, it cannot continue for lack of stack space. So it has to abort, without fully initializing that class, so it throws a NoClassDefFoundError. At least that's my guess.

Comment: @k_g Codegolf. Less lines. As I said, this code has MANY issues. Ignore them, or write them up to code golf.

Comment: @PatB See my above comment.

Comment: The Java Virtual Machine is unable to find or load `java.security.SecureRandom`. Re-installation of Java might solve your problem.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt But then wouldnt it throw a stack overflow error?

Comment: @user2382867 No it has not. Read the error message: "Could not initialize class java.security.SecureRandom". It could find it, it just could not initialize it. Unfortunately it doesn't print the reason why it could not initialize it.

Comment: @Erwin Bolwidt Then your guess would be right. These are the only things that comes up my mind.

Comment: This page has some hints. It's a link so I wouldn't dare post it as an answer. http://javaeesupportpatterns.blogspot.sg/2012/07/javalangnoclassdeffounderror-how-to.html

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt Your guess seems to be correct, even though it doesnt make sense to me. I tried changing some lines of code and I end up still getting the same `NoClassDef` error, but at different parts of the stack.